# Появления блока с графиком

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, функции

Есть такой код с выпадающим списком и скриптом , который отрисовует графики:

```
<ul class="navigation">
<a class="main" href="#url">Choose year</a>
<li class="n1"><input type="button" value="2010" data-block-id="chart_div"></li>
<li class="n2"><input type="button" value="2011" data-block-id="chart_div1"></li>
<li class="n3"><input type="button" value="2012" data-block-id="chart_div2"></li>
<li class="n4"><input type="button" value="2013" data-block-id="chart_div3"></li>
<li class="n5"><input type="button" value="2014" data-block-id="chart_div4"></li>
</ul>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2010);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2011);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2012);



google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2013);

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2014);

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2015);

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2016);

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2017);

function drawChart2017() {

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Team');
data.addColumn('date', 'asd');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip','p': {'html': true}});

data.addRows([

['Wizoria', new Date(2017,01,18),createCustomHTMLContent('Wizoria','Mirgorod','2')],

['Wizoria', new Date(2017,01,18),createCustomHTMLContent('Wizoria','Mirgorod','1')],

['Bumer', new Date(2017,02,21),createCustomHTMLContent('Bumer','Kiev','3')],

['Olimp', new Date(2017,05,02),createCustomHTMLContent('Olimp','Krivoj-rog','Big')],

['Apelsin', new Date(2017,05,05),createCustomHTMLContent('Apelsin','Sevastopol','4')],

['Raketa', new Date(2017,05,05),createCustomHTMLContent('Raketa','Evpatoriya','3')],

['Dolmen', new Date(2017,05,10),createCustomHTMLContent('Dolmen','Harkov','1')],

['Dolmen', new Date(2017,05,11),createCustomHTMLContent('Dolmen','Harkov','4')],

['Dolmen', new Date(2017,05,11),createCustomHTMLContent('Dolmen','Harkov','2')],

['Sputnik', new Date(2017,09,01),createCustomHTMLContent('Sputnik','Nezhyn','2')], 

['Sputnik', new Date(2017,09,01),createCustomHTMLContent('Sputnik','Nezhyn','1')] 

]);

var options = {
legend: {position: 'none'},
height: 450,
lineWidth:4,

curveType: 'function',

lineDashStyle:[15,2,3,3],
pointSize:10,
colors:['#af0000'],
tooltip: {isHtml: true,trigger:'selection'},
hAxis:{
textPosition:'none'
},
vAxis:{
textStyle : {
fontSize: 14,

}
}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div7'));

chart.draw(data, options);
}

function drawChart2016() {

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Team');
data.addColumn('date', 'asd');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip','p': {'html': true}});

data.addRows([

['Smart Cinema SEC Sky Park', new Date(2016,04,04),createCustomHTMLContent('Smart Cinema SEC Sky Park','Vinnica','1')],

['Smart Cinema SEC Sky Park', new Date(2016,04,04),createCustomHTMLContent('Smart Cinema SEC Sky Park','Vinnica','2')],

['Smart Cinema SEC Sky Park', new Date(2016,04,04),createCustomHTMLContent('Smart Cinema SEC Sky Park','Vinnica','3')],

['Smart Cinema SEC Sky Park', new Date(2016,04,04),createCustomHTMLContent('Smart Cinema SEC Sky Park','Vinnica','4')],

['Smart Cinema SEC Sky Park', new Date(2016,04,04),createCustomHTMLContent('Smart Cinema SEC Sky Park','Vinnica','5')],

['Smart Cinema SEC Sky Park', new Date(2016,04,04),createCustomHTMLContent('Smart Cinema SEC Sky Park','Vinnica','6')],

['Smart Cinema SEC Sky Park', new Date(2016,04,04),createCustomHTMLContent('Smart Cinema SEC Sky Park','Vinnica','7')],

['Adrenalin City', new Date(2016,04,26),createCustomHTMLContent('Adrenalin City','Luck','Blue')],

['Premiera', new Date(2016,05,04),createCustomHTMLContent('Premiera','Pervomajsk','1')],

['City', new Date(2016,05,06),createCustomHTMLContent('City','Chervonograd','1')],

['SEC New Way Wizoria', new Date(2016,05,17),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC New Way Wizoria','Harkov','1')],

['SEC New Way Wizoria', new Date(2016,05,17),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC New Way Wizoria','Harkov','2')],

['SEC New Way Wizoria', new Date(2016,05,17),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC New Way Wizoria','Harkov','3')],

['SEC New Way Wizoria', new Date(2016,05,17),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC New Way Wizoria','Harkov','4')],

['SEC New Way Wizoria', new Date(2016,05,17),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC New Way Wizoria','Harkov','5')],

['SEC New Way Wizoria', new Date(2016,05,17),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC New Way Wizoria','Harkov','6')],

['Dolmen', new Date(2016,05,17),createCustomHTMLContent('Dolmen','Harkov','1')],

['SEC Dafi Multiplex', new Date(2016,05,27),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Dafi Multiplex','Harkov','1')],

['SEC Dafi Multiplex', new Date(2016,05,27),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Dafi Multiplex','Harkov','2')],

['SEC Dafi Multiplex', new Date(2016,05,27),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Dafi Multiplex','Harkov','3')],

['SEC Dafi Multiplex', new Date(2016,05,27),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Dafi Multiplex','Harkov','4')],

['SEC Dafi Multiplex', new Date(2016,05,27),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Dafi Multiplex','Harkov','5')],

['SEC Dafi Multiplex', new Date(2016,05,27),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Dafi Multiplex','Harkov','6')],

['SEC Dafi Multiplex', new Date(2016,05,27),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Dafi Multiplex','Harkov','7')],

['Moscow', new Date(2016,06,02),createCustomHTMLContent('Moscow','Odessa','7')],

['Kinoland', new Date(2016,06,06),createCustomHTMLContent('Kinoland','Harkov','4')],

['Kinoland', new Date(2016,06,06),createCustomHTMLContent('Kinoland','Harkov','5')],

['SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino', new Date(2016,06,12),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino','Kyiv','4DX')],

['SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino', new Date(2016,06,12),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino','Kyiv','Cinetech+ 1')],

['SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino', new Date(2016,06,12),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino','Kyiv','Cinetech+ 2')],

['SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino', new Date(2016,06,12),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino','Kyiv','Cinetech+ 3')],

['SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino', new Date(2016,06,12),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino','Kyiv','Cinetech+ 4')],

['SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino', new Date(2016,06,12),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino','Kyiv','Cinetech+ 5')],

['SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino', new Date(2016,06,12),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino','Kyiv','Cinetech+ 6')],

['SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino', new Date(2016,06,12),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino','Kyiv','Cinetech+ 7')],

['SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino', new Date(2016,06,12),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino','Kyiv','Cinetech+ 8')],

['SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino', new Date(2016,06,12),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino','Kyiv','VIP 1')],

['SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino', new Date(2016,06,12),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino','Kyiv','VIP 2')],

['SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino', new Date(2016,06,12),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Bloсkbuster Planeta Kino','Kyiv','VIP 3')],

['SEC Ocean Plaza Cinema Citi', new Date(2016,08,08),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Ocean Plaza Cinema Citi','Kyiv','1')],

['Oktyabr', new Date(2016,11,09),createCustomHTMLContent('Oktyabr','Bilhorod-Dnistrovskui','2')],

['SEC Konkord Wizoria', new Date(2016,11,16),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Konkord Wizoria','Poltava','1')],

['SEC Konkord Wizoria', new Date(2016,11,16),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Konkord Wizoria','Poltava','2')],

['SEC Konkord Wizoria', new Date(2016,11,16),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Konkord Wizoria','Poltava','3')],

['SEC Billa Prime', new Date(2016,11,17),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Billa Prime','Nikopol','1')],

['Pobeda', new Date(2016,12,03),createCustomHTMLContent('Pobeda','Melitopol','3')],

['SEC Lyubava', new Date(2016,12,06),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Lyubava','Cherkassy','4')],

['SEC Apelsin VIP', new Date(2016,12,08),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Apelsin VIP','Sevastopol','VIP')],

['SEC Musson', new Date(2016,12,11),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Musson','Sevastopol','7')],

['SEC Kyiv', new Date(2016,12,20),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Kyiv','Harkov','3')],

['Wizoria, EC Kolos', new Date(2016,12,25),createCustomHTMLContent('Wizoria, EC Kolos','Poltava','1')],

['Wizoria, EC Kolos', new Date(2016,12,25),createCustomHTMLContent('Wizoria, EC Kolos','Poltava','2')]

]);

var options = {
legend: {position: 'none'},
height: 450,
lineWidth:4,

curveType: 'function',

lineDashStyle:[15,2,3,3],
pointSize:10,
colors:['#af0000'],
tooltip: {isHtml: true,trigger:'selection'},
hAxis:{
textPosition:'none'
},
vAxis:{
textStyle : {
fontSize: 14,

}
}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div6'));

chart.draw(data, options);
}

function drawChart2015() {

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Team');
data.addColumn('date', 'asd');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip','p': {'html': true}});

data.addRows([

['Kyiv', new Date(2015,02,24),createCustomHTMLContent('Kyiv','Harkov','3')],

['Kyiv', new Date(2015,02,24),createCustomHTMLContent('Kyiv','Harkov','6')],

['Dovzhenko', new Date(2015,02,25),createCustomHTMLContent('Dovzhenko','Harkov','4')],

['SEC Dnipro Plaza Multiplex', new Date(2015,04,09),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Dnipro Plaza Multiplex','Cherkassy','Koen')],

['SEC Lyubava Multiplex', new Date(2015,04,09),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Lyubava Multiplex','Cherkassy','Strip')],

['SEC TsUM', new Date(2015,05,07),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC TsUM','Dneprodzerzhinsk','3')],

['SEC TsUM', new Date(2015,05,07),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC TsUM','Dneprodzerzhinsk','4')],

['ANGA 3D', new Date(2015,05,13),createCustomHTMLContent('ANGA 3D','Nairoby-Kenia','1')],

['ANGA 3D', new Date(2015,05,13),createCustomHTMLContent('ANGA 3D','Nairoby-Kenia','2')],

['SEC Atmosfera Multiplex', new Date(2015,07,30),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Atmosfera Multiplex','Kiev','3')],

['SEC Atmosfera Multiplex', new Date(2015,07,30),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Atmosfera Multiplex','Kiev','4')],

['Zlata', new Date(2015,08,23),createCustomHTMLContent('Zlata','Truskavec','1')],

['SEC Tokyo', new Date(2015,09,22),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Tokyo','Uzhgorod','2')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX SEC Forum', new Date(2015,09,25),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX SEC Forum','Lvov','1')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX SEC Forum', new Date(2015,09,25),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX SEC Forum','Lvov','2')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX SEC Forum', new Date(2015,09,25),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX SEC Forum','Lvov','3')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX SEC Forum', new Date(2015,09,25),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX SEC Forum','Lvov','4 (4DX)')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX SEC Forum', new Date(2015,09,25),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX SEC Forum','Lvov','5')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX SEC Forum', new Date(2015,09,25),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX SEC Forum','Lvov','6')],

['SEC Terminal', new Date(2015,10,02),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Terminal','Dzhankoj','4')],

['Poznan', new Date(2015,10,05),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Terminal','Harkov','1')],

['Poznan', new Date(2015,10,05),createCustomHTMLContent('Poznan','Harkov','2')],

['Savona', new Date(2015,10,22),createCustomHTMLContent('Savona','Mariupol','Red')],

['Poznan', new Date(2015,12,02),createCustomHTMLContent('Poznan','Harkov','1')],

['Poznan', new Date(2015,12,02),createCustomHTMLContent('Poznan','Harkov','3')],

['KinoMario', new Date(2015,12,10),createCustomHTMLContent('KinoMario','Berdichiv','1')],

['Chaplin', new Date(2015,12,26),createCustomHTMLContent('Chaplin','Stryj','4')]







]);

var options = {
legend: {position: 'none'},
height: 450,
lineWidth:4,

curveType: 'function',

lineDashStyle:[15,2,3,3],
pointSize:10,
colors:['#af0000'],
tooltip: {isHtml: true,trigger:'selection'},
hAxis:{
textPosition:'none'
},
vAxis:{
textStyle : {
fontSize: 14,

}
}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div5'));

chart.draw(data, options);
}

function drawChart2014() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Team');
data.addColumn('date', 'asd');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip','p': {'html': true}});

data.addRows([

['Planeta Kino IMAX', new Date(2014,01,07),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX','Harkov','4')],

['Chaplin', new Date(2014,01,09),createCustomHTMLContent('Chaplin','Dolina','1')],

['Kupecheskij dom', new Date(2014,01,21),createCustomHTMLContent('Kupecheskij dom','Slavyansk','1')],

['SEC Dafi Kronverk', new Date(2014,02,01),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Dafi Kronverk','Harkov','3')],

['SEC Dafi Kronverk', new Date(2014,02,01),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Dafi Kronverk','Harkov','4')],

['SEC Dafi Kronverk', new Date(2014,02,01),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Dafi Kronverk','Harkov','5')],

['SEC Dafi Kronverk', new Date(2014,02,01),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Dafi Kronverk','Harkov','6 (4DX)')],

['SEC Dafi Kronverk', new Date(2014,02,01),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Dafi Kronverk','Harkov','7')],

['SEC SKY Mall Kronverk', new Date(2014,02,05),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC SKY Mall Kronverk','Kiev','10')],

['SEC SKY Mall Kronverk', new Date(2014,02,05),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC SKY Mall Kronverk','Kiev','3')],

['SEC SKY Mall Kronverk', new Date(2014,02,05),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC SKY Mall Kronverk','Kiev','4')],

['SEC SKY Mall Kronverk', new Date(2014,02,05),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC SKY Mall Kronverk','Kiev','5')],

['SEC SKY Mall Kronverk', new Date(2014,02,05),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC SKY Mall Kronverk','Kiev','6')],

['SEC SKY Mall Kronverk', new Date(2014,02,05),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC SKY Mall Kronverk','Kiev','9l')],

['SEC Terminal', new Date(2014,05,08),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Terminal','Dzhankoj','1')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX Kotovskogo', new Date(2014,05,15),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX Kotovskogo','Odessa','1')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX Kotovskogo', new Date(2014,05,15),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX Kotovskogo','Odessa','2')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX Kotovskogo', new Date(2014,05,15),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX Kotovskogo','Odessa','3')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX Kotovskogo', new Date(2014,05,15),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX Kotovskogo','Odessa','4')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX Kotovskogo', new Date(2014,05,15),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX Kotovskogo','Odessa','5')],

['Pemer city', new Date(2014,05,17),createCustomHTMLContent('Pemer city','Luck','1')],

['Pemer city', new Date(2014,05,17),createCustomHTMLContent('Pemer city','Luck','2')],

['Pemer city', new Date(2014,05,17),createCustomHTMLContent('Pemer city','Luck','3')],

['Pemer city', new Date(2014,05,17),createCustomHTMLContent('Pemer city','Luck','4')],

['SEC Lyubava Multiplex', new Date(2014,05,27),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Lyubava Multiplex','Cherkassy','Ford')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX Tairova', new Date(2014,05,29),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX Tairova','Odessa','1')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX Tairova', new Date(2014,05,29),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX Tairova','Odessa','2')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX Tairova', new Date(2014,05,29),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX Tairova','Odessa','3')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX Tairova', new Date(2014,05,29),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX Tairova','Odessa','4')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX Tairova', new Date(2014,05,29),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX Tairova','Odessa','6(4DX)')],

['SEC ART Mall Kinodrom', new Date(2014,07,26),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC ART Mall Kinodrom','Kiev','1')],

['SEC Musson', new Date(2014,10,24),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Musson','Sevastopol','5')],

['SEC Musson', new Date(2014,10,24),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Musson','Sevastopol','6')],

['SEC Dnipro Plaza Multiplex', new Date(2014,11,20),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Dnipro Plaza Multiplex','Cherkassy','de Funes')],

['Crimea', new Date(2014,12,09),createCustomHTMLContent('Crimea','Feodosiya','Small')],

['Konkord',new Date(2014,12,17),createCustomHTMLContent('Konkord','Poltava',2)],

['SEC Rivera Odessa Kino',new Date(2014,12,20),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Rivera Odessa Kino','Odessa',4)],

['SEC Rivera Odessa Kino', new Date(2014,12,20),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Rivera Odessa Kino','Odessa',5)],

['Europa', new Date(2014,12,22),createCustomHTMLContent('Europa','Borispil','1')],

['Akura Cent Kinodrom', new Date(2014,12,25),createCustomHTMLContent('Akura Cent Kinodrom','Kiev','1')],

['Ukraina', new Date(2014,12,26),createCustomHTMLContent('Ukraina','Kerch','Red')],


]);

var options = {
legend: {position: 'none'},
height: 450,
lineWidth:4,

curveType: 'function',

lineDashStyle:[15,2,3,3],
pointSize:10,
colors:['#af0000'],
tooltip: {isHtml: true,trigger:'selection'},
hAxis:{
textPosition:'none'
},
vAxis:{
textStyle : {
fontSize: 14,

}
}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div4'));

chart.draw(data, options);
}

function drawChart2013() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Team');
data.addColumn('date', 'asd');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip','p': {'html': true}});

data.addRows([
['Savona', new Date(2013,02,15),createCustomHTMLContent('Savona','Mariupol','Green')],
['Savona', new Date(2013,02,15),createCustomHTMLContent('Savona','Mariupol','Blue')],
['SEC Jazz', new Date(2013,02,22),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Jazz','Severodoneck','Oskar')],
['Cіnema', new Date(2013,04,22),createCustomHTMLContent('Cіnema','Kamyanec-Podolskij',1)],
['SEC Bloсkbuster Multiplex',new Date(2013,04,29),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Bloсkbuster Multiplex','Kiev',10)],
['Cіnema',new Date(2013,06,04),createCustomHTMLContent('Cіnema','Kamyanec-Podolskij',2)],

['Konkord',new Date(2013,06,06),createCustomHTMLContent('Konkord','Poltava',1)],

['Multiplex SEC Oazis', new Date(2013,06,21),createCustomHTMLContent('Multiplex SEC Oazis','Hmelnickij','Kajdanovskij')],

['SEC Bloсkbuster Multiplex', new Date(2013,06,26),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Bloсkbuster Multiplex','Kiev','4')],
['Multiplex SEC Komodi', new Date(2013,06,26),createCustomHTMLContent('Multiplex SEC Komodi','Kiev','Grinko')],
['Multiplex SEC Donetsk City', new Date(2013,06,27),createCustomHTMLContent('Multiplex SEC Donetsk City','Doneck','Smoktunovskij')],
['SEC Bloсkbuster Multiplex', new Date(2013,07,05),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Bloсkbuster Multiplex','Kiev','9')],
['SEC Gorodok', new Date(2013,07,15),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Gorodok','Priluki','1')],
['Leningrad', new Date(2013,07,29),createCustomHTMLContent('Leningrad','Kiev','Medium')],
['Florence', new Date(2013,07,30),createCustomHTMLContent('Florence','Kiev','2')],
['Florence', new Date(2013,07,30),createCustomHTMLContent('Florence','Kiev','3')],

['SEC Stolitsa', new Date(2013,08,05),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Stolitsa','Alchevsk','2')],

['Spartak', new Date(2013,08,07),createCustomHTMLContent('Spartak','Simferopol','VIP')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX', new Date(2013,09,04),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX','Harkov','3')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX', new Date(2013,09,04),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX','Lvov','5')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX', new Date(2013,09,19),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX','Sumy','1')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX', new Date(2013,09,19),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX','Sumy','2')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX', new Date(2013,09,19),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX','Sumy','3')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX', new Date(2013,09,19),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX','Sumy','4')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX', new Date(2013,09,19),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX','Sumy','5')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX', new Date(2013,09,24),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX','Lvov','3')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX', new Date(2013,09,25),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX','Harkov','2')],

['Bratislava', new Date(2013,09,30),createCustomHTMLContent('Bratislava','Kiev','1')],

['Leipzig', new Date(2013,09,30),createCustomHTMLContent('Leipzig','Kiev','Small')],

['Russia', new Date(2013,10,03),createCustomHTMLContent('Russia','Harkov','Red')],

['KinoKult', new Date(2013,10,14),createCustomHTMLContent('KinoKult','Doneck','Red')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX', new Date(2013,11,05),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX','Odessa','4')],

['SEC Tokyo', new Date(2013,12,10),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Tokyo','Uzhgorod','1')],

['Pobeda', new Date(2013,12,15),createCustomHTMLContent('Pobeda','Melitopol','2')],

['Crimea', new Date(2013,12,16),createCustomHTMLContent('Crimea','Feodosiya','1')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX', new Date(2013,12,18),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX','Harkov','6 (4DX)')],

['Planeta Kino IMAX', new Date(2013,12,19),createCustomHTMLContent('Planeta Kino IMAX','Odessa','1')],

['Rodina', new Date(2013,12,22),createCustomHTMLContent('Rodina','Kramatorsk','1')],

['Sapfir', new Date(2013,12,22),createCustomHTMLContent('Sapfir','Slavyansk','1')],

['Zagreb', new Date(2013,12,25),createCustomHTMLContent('Zagreb','Kiev','1')],

['Lumier', new Date(2013,12,27),createCustomHTMLContent('Lumier','Ladyzhin','1')],

['Domion', new Date(2013,12,28),createCustomHTMLContent('Domion','Uzhgorod','1')]

]);

var options = {
legend: {position: 'none'},
height: 450,
lineWidth:4,

curveType: 'function',

lineDashStyle:[15,2,3,3],
pointSize:10,
colors:['#af0000'],
tooltip: {isHtml: true,trigger:'selection'},
hAxis:{
textPosition:'none'
},
vAxis:{
textStyle : {
fontSize: 14,

}
}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div3'));

chart.draw(data, options);
}



function drawChart2012() {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Team');
data.addColumn('date', 'asd');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip','p': {'html': true}});

data.addRows([
['SM Galaktika', new Date(2012,02,25),createCustomHTMLContent('SM Galaktika','Kirovograd','Red')],
['SM Galaktika', new Date(2012,03,03),createCustomHTMLContent('SM Galaktika','Poltava',2)],
['Pobeda', new Date(2012,03,07),createCustomHTMLContent('Pobeda','Sumy',1)],
['Multiplex SEC Dnipro Plaza', new Date(2012,03,27),createCustomHTMLContent('Multiplex SEC Dnipro Plaza','Kerch','Green')],
['Raketa',new Date(2012,03,28),createCustomHTMLContent('Raketa','Dnepropetrovsk',1)],
['SM Apelsin',new Date(2012,03,29),createCustomHTMLContent('SM Apelsin','Sverdlovsk',1)],
['Ukraine', new Date(2012,04,13),createCustomHTMLContent('Ukraine','Dnepropetrovsk',4)],
['Multiplex SEC Dnipro Plaza', new Date(2012,05,08),createCustomHTMLContent('Multiplex SEC Dnipro Plaza','Sevastopol','1')],
['Multiplex Salyut', new Date(2012,05,08),createCustomHTMLContent('Multiplex Salyut','Sevastopol','2')],
['SEC Palladium', new Date(2012,05,26),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Palladium','Sevastopol','3')],
['SEC Palladium', new Date(2012,05,26),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Palladium','Sevastopol','4')],
['SEC Palladium', new Date(2012,05,26),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Palladium','Izmail','1')],
['SM Galaktika', new Date(2012,07,14),createCustomHTMLContent('SM Galaktika','Kerch','1')],
['SM Galaktika', new Date(2012,07,14),createCustomHTMLContent('SM Galaktika','Poltava','3')],

['SM TsUM', new Date(2012,07,28),createCustomHTMLContent('SM TsUM','Koreiz','1')],

['SM TsUM', new Date(2012,07,28),createCustomHTMLContent('SM TsUM','Koreiz','1')],

['Dovzhenko', new Date(2012,09,01),createCustomHTMLContent('Dovzhenko','Koreiz','1')],

['Pobeda', new Date(2012,09,02),createCustomHTMLContent('Pobeda','Koreiz','1')],

['Pobeda', new Date(2012,10,14),createCustomHTMLContent('Pobeda','Koreiz','1')],

['Kinodrom', new Date(2012,11,23),createCustomHTMLContent('Kinodrom','Koreiz','1')],

['SEC Ttavriya V', new Date(2012,11,27),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Ttavriya V','Koreiz','1')],

['SEC Gyuzel', new Date(2012,12,02),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Gyuzel','Koreiz','1')],

['SEC DepoD', new Date(2012,12,24),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC DepoD','Koreiz','1')],

['SEC DepoD', new Date(2012,12,24),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC DepoD','Koreiz','1')],

['SEC Stolitsa', new Date(2012,12,26),createCustomHTMLContent('SEC Stolitsa','Koreiz','1')],

['Kinomaks 3D', new Date(2012,12,28),createCustomHTMLContent('Kinomaks 3D','Koreiz','1')],

['Spartak', new Date(2012,12,30),createCustomHTMLContent('Spartak','Koreiz','1')]



]);

var options = {
legend: {position: 'none'},
height: 450,
lineWidth:4,

curveType: 'function',

lineDashStyle:[15,2,3,3],
pointSize:10,
colors:['#af0000'],
tooltip: {isHtml: true,trigger:'selection'},
hAxis:{

textPosition:'none'

},
vAxis:{
textStyle : {
fontSize: 14,

}

}
};

var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));

chart.draw(data, options);
}


function createCustomHTMLContent(name,city, hall) {
return '<div>' +
'<br/>' +
'<table class="medals_layout" style="font-family:DINPro">' + '<tr>' +
'<td><b>Name: </b>' + name + '</td>'+ '</tr>' + '<tr>' +
'<td><b>City: </b>' + city + '</td>' + '</tr>' + '<tr>' +
'<td><b>Hall: </b>' + hall + '</td>' + '</tr>'+ '</table>' + '</div>';
}


</script>

<div id="charts">

<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<div id="chart_div1" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<div id="chart_div2" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<div id="chart_div3" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<div id="chart_div4" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<div id="chart_div5" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<div id="chart_div6" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<div id="chart_div7" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

</div>
```

И есть такой код , который при клике должен показывать нужный график:

```
var $buttons = $(".navigation input");

    $buttons.on("click", function() {
      alert("hello");
      var blockId = $(this).data("blockid");
      $("#" + blockId).show();
    });
```

При клике даже hello не выводиться. Скрипт - в отдельном файле, находиться в самом низу страницы. что может быть не так?

Comment: 1. Что выдает Консоль браузера? (Клавиша F12). 2. Нет объявления библиотек jQuery и что за переменная google, там тоже скорей всего библиотека должна быть.

Answer (score 0):

Очень сложно понять столько кода, одного блока для примера было бы достаточно.

Раз у вас не выводится даже `alert`, есть ошибка в `js`, либо ситнаксическая либо логическая.

Посмотрите на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9pukvajy/5/).

```
var $buttons = $(".navigation input");

$buttons.on("click", function() {
  var blockId = $(this).data("block-id");
  $("#" + blockId).css({visibility:"",position:""});
});
```

Кстати, вы опечатались, когда брали атрибут `block-id`.

Comment: попробывал  вывести алерт на клик, так не высвечивается , скорее всего скрипт не может обратиться к елементу, или как?

Comment: @CTACO23 Что не высвечивается? Лучше всего покажите код. Отредактируйте вопрос и покажите ваш код. Там под вопросом есть кнопка "Править".

Comment: вопрос обновил, еще на фидл закинул: https://jsfiddle.net/9pukvajy/

Comment: @CTACO23 я сделал фидл рабочим, можете глянуть.